# USB device to draw constant small current to prevent power bank from shutting off

Tags: usb, battery

Most external USB power banks nowadays will shut off if the device connected to them stops drawing current.

This guy modded an USB voltage monitor by adding two resistors to accomplish basically what I need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkWhodi41f8

I was wondering however if there's already such a device on the market that does this.

Comment: I connected a USB current monitoring device, which is a pass-through that shows voltage and amperes. After the usual time-out, the power bank shut off. I had expected that the LED indicators would keep the bank on. I also connected a ChargieA to the monitor but even the combination of the two was insufficient to keep the bank on. That excludes two devices from practical consideration.

Answer (score 1):

On a more positive, productive note, my second test was successful, but may not fit your requirements.

[image: USB PCB LED flashlight]

The image is a composite of the powerbank, USB monitor and a PCB USB LED "flashlight." It appears that I purchased these (10 pcs, US$6.50 with shipping) [from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10PCS-Card-Lamp-Bulb-Led-Keychain-Mini-LED-Night-Light-Portable-USB-Power-White-/311525223940) for a nominal cost.

The current draw still appears to be 0.00 amperes, which is a physical impossibility, but the powerbank remained on for at least three minutes, about two minutes longer than without the PCB USB LED inserted.